# Symfony2, How to register an extension by using the `addExtension()` method on your main `Environment` object

Tags: symfony, twig

I would like to load a new extension in a `symfony2` project for `twig` but I don't know where should I put line below to work :

```
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader, $config);
$twig->addExtension(new Twig_Extension_Debug());
```

Any tutorials for http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/dump.html ?

Comment: I have added line above to `/vendor/twig/lib/Twig/Environment.php` in `__construct` function. and it is working fine.

Comment: I know this is very old, but in case anyone has just found it, don't do as PMoubed has suggested above. For a start, the vendor/ dir shouldn't even be in your version control. Do as the same person has put in the accepted answer below :)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I could add debug for twig like below :

```
# app/config/config.yml
services:
    acme_hello.twig.extension.debug:
        class:        Twig_Extension_Debug
        tags:
             - { name: 'twig.extension' }
```

Look [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#debugging) for more details;

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a service with `twig.extension` tag. See [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/dic_tags.html#enabling-custom-twig-extensions)

Answer (score 0):

There is also a cookbook on Symfony documentation about how to create a custom twig extension for Symfony.

You can take a look at it right [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html)

Regards,
Matt

Comment: Please do not just post a link to a ressource but add the relevant information.